Ews FileAttachment.Load returns empty file
I am using the Ews OAuth2 and I am getting well email and email information, but when I try to get the attachment files, returns empty files.
Here is my code:
 SearchFilter filter = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And, new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.IsRead, false));
                var findResults = ewsClient.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.SentItems, aqsFilter, new ItemView(50));
                //var findResults = ewsClient.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, filter, new ItemView(50));

                foreach (Item mailItem in findResults.Result)
                {
                    PropertySet props = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties, EmailMessageSchema.Attachments, EmailMessageSchema.MimeContent);

                    EmailMessage message = EmailMessage.Bind(ewsClient, mailItem.Id, props).Result;
                   
                    Console.WriteLine($"Subject: {message.Subject}");
                    Console.WriteLine($"From: {message.From.Name} : {message.From.Address}");

                    if (message.HasAttachments && message.Attachments[0] is FileAttachment)
                    {
                        if (message.HasAttachments && message.Attachments[0] is FileAttachment)
                        {
                            message.IsRead = true;
                            foreach (FileAttachment fileAttachment in message.Attachments)
                            {
                                string ls_fileNamePath = Path.Combine(@"C:\DocsUpload\EmailTmp\", fileAttachment.Name);

                                fileAttachment.Load(ls_fileNamePath);

                                Console.WriteLine($"Attachment Downloaded: {fileAttachment.Name}");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

What could be wrong?

Solved with the following change:
                                fileAttachment.Load().Wait();
                            if (fileAttachment.Content != null && fileAttachment.Content.Length > 0)
                            {
                                string filePath = Path.Combine(directoryPath, fileAttachment.Name);
                                File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, fileAttachment.Content);
                                Console.WriteLine($"Attachment saved to: {filePath}");
                            }

